# Cocoa binding does't work when changing property in -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, binding, key-value-observing

So I have this textField `someField` bound to a property `someText` in InterfaceBuilder (IB).
Anywhere in my code, when I change `someText`, `someField` content updates accordingly, and vice versa.

Anywhere but in the method `-observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`

Indeed I'm observing `someText` so that when the value in the text field is changed, the binding modifies `someText` and I can perform some validation on it.
When this happens, I can do the following:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
    [...]
    //keyPath is @"someText"
    if (enteredValueIsNotValid) {
        [object setValue:validValue forKey:keyPath];
    }
    [...]
}
```

After calling `[object setValue:validValue forKey:keyPath]`, `someText` took the value `validValue`. Just like expected. But because a biding is in place, I also expect to see the `validValue` to show up in my text field `someField`. But it doesn't happen !!

I'm obviously missing something but can't figure out what. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Cheers.

Comment: Hey Baldoph, curious as to why you deleted your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36502630/2415822).  Did you find an answer?

Comment: @JAL Just saw your question now I'm sorry! I totally forgot about why I needed that, of why I removed it... not of much help here I'm afraid :/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of validating the value in -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:, you should do this:

```
-(BOOL)validateSomeText:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)outError
{
    ...
    if (enteredValueIsNotValid)
        *ioValue = validValue;
    return YES;
}
```

This should work with bindings (and there's the option to validate the field contents immediately, i.e. before the field “attempts to resign as the responder”), but -setValue:forKey: doesn't call it and according to the documentation your setters should neither.

For details, see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Validation.html